# Confused by a Makefile error "src/Sort.cpp:3:18: fatal error: Sort.h: no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, makefile

**1.** My file structure is:

```
build/
include/
     -Sort.h
src/
     -Sort.cpp
     -main.cpp
```

**2.** My Makefile:

```
C++ = g++
SRCPATH := ./src
BUILDPATH := ./build
SORTINCPATH := ./include
TARGET := $(BUILDPATH)/sort

CPPFLAGS := -c -g -Wall -O0
INCPATH := -I./ -I$(SORTINCPATH)

CPPFILES += $(wildcard $(SRCPATH)/*.cpp)
CFILES += $(wildcard $(SRCPATH)/*.c)
HEADFILES += $(wildcard $(SORTINCPATH)/*.h)

CPPOBJS += $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o)
COBJS += $(CFILES:.c=.o)


.PHONY : all
all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(CPPOBJS) $(COBJS)
        $(C++) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $(CPPOBJS) $(COBJS)

%.o : %.c $(HEADFILES)
        $(C++) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCPATH) $< -o $@

%.O : %.cpp $(HEADFILES)
        $(C++) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCPATH) $< -o $@

.PHONY : clean
clean:
        -rm $(TARGET) $(COBJS) $(CPPOBJS)
```

**3.**  Sort.h

[sort.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMzPk.png)

**4.** Sort.cpp

[sort-1.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmwmR.png)

[sort-2.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHBjc.png)

**5.** When I run make, it shows the following:

```
g++  -c -g -Wall -O0  -c -o src/Sort.o src/Sort.cpp
```

and says "src/Sort.cpp:3:18: fatal error: Sort.h: no such file or directory".

I hope you can help me find out where the problem is.

Thank you so much!

Comment: That's a compilation (not a makefile) error, you also nee to show `Sort.cpp`

Comment: Are the object files generated from `.cpp` sources meant to have a `.o` (lower case) extension or `.O`?  You appear to have mixed the two causing `make` to use an implicit rule.

Comment: The Makefile looks more complicated than necessary to me (because I cannot understand it easily). For these standard tasks like compiling a C++ file to an object file you can rely on the built-in rules and simply set CPPFLAGS (which are used by the built-in rules) to contain the include directory flags.

Comment: @RichardCritten   Just modify CPPOBJS += $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o) to CPPOBJS += $(CPPFILES:.cpp=.O),  that is, to big O.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, yeah, I want to learn how to use make to realise automatic compilation. ^_^ thanks a lot.

Comment: @JustinFinnerty Thanks, actually, I added it in the following command "$(C++) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCPATH) $< -o $@" as a substitution.

Comment: @G.M.That's right !!! thanks a lot !!! I didn't notice that !

Comment: Another error in my Makefile---add '-c' to CPPFLAGS, causing linker fail.